Pulse audio server with remote mic/speakers
This is my first idea to do this at all, till now any sound system was installed and just worked, locally, without special needs.
I would know if this is possible and how to do such a thing:
I have ubuntu server 22.04. I'm not using sound there, and even don't know if there is any sound system installed/working (how to check it?)
Now I want install sound server and sent audio via network:
from/to Linux Mint laptop and from/to another devices, like OpenWRT.
I've heard (few minutes ago) about pipewire, but as I can see there is no OpenWRT packages for this. And pulseaudio is available for this system, so probably its the best choice here.
But how to start with this setup? Is it possible at all?
From practical point of view I want to run a script (I think as a daemon) on server, which will produce some audio to play on desktop/openWRT and also provide audio streams to handle on server.
